# Count the occurrences of couples of elements in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's a sample of the database I'm working with :

```
{'type': {0: 'TV Show', 1: 'Movie', 2: 'Movie', 3: 'Movie', 4: 'Movie'},
 'director': {0: nan,
  1: 'Jorge Michel Grau',
  2: 'Gilbert Chan',
  3: 'Shane Acker',
  4: 'Robert Luketic'},
 'country': {0: 'Brazil',
  1: 'Mexico',
  2: 'Singapore',
  3: 'Poland, United States',
  4: 'Norway, Poland, United States'},
 'rating': {0: 'TV-MA', 1: 'TV-MA', 2: 'R', 3: 'PG-13', 4: 'PG-13'}}
```

What I'm trying to do is count how many times two countries (even more than two if possible) collaborated on a movies/tv show. Using the provided sample, I'd find that the USA and Poland collaborated twice, USA and Norway once, and no collaborations for the rest of the countries. Here's the code that I managed to make :

```
# This function would count the number of occurrences of each country in the column
def count(data, column) :
    return Counter([thing.strip() for thing in data[column].fillna('missing') for thing in thing.split(',')])

# And this one would count the occurrences of couples of countries together
def count_tuple(data, column) :
    a, b = zip(*count(data, column).most_common())
    s = pd.DataFrame(columns=a, index=a)
    
    for l in a :
        mask = data[column].fillna('missing').apply(lambda z: l in z)
        df = data[mask]
        c, d = zip(*count(df, column).most_common())
        for k in c :
            if k !='' :
                occur = count(df, column)[k]
                s.loc[l,k] = occur
    return s.fillna(0)
```

This function would return a `dataframe` with the occurrence of each couple of countries. As usual I don't think this method is efficient, Could there be another way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for all combinations of `country` columns values in nested list comprehension with hashable sets called `forozenset`s for count with not important order, it means `(United States, Poland)` is same like `(Poland, United States)` for count:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
from collections import Counter

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031/2901002
def all_subsets(ss):
    return list(chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(ss, x), range(2, len(ss)+1))))

L = [frozenset(y) for x in df['country'].fillna('missing') 
                  for y in all_subsets(x.split(', '))]
print (L)

out = Counter(L)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':out.keys(), 'col2': out.values()})
print (df)
                              col1  col2
0          (United States, Poland)     2
1                 (Norway, Poland)     1
2          (United States, Norway)     1
3  (United States, Norway, Poland)     1
```

Or you can sorting values to tuples:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
from collections import Counter

def all_subsets(ss):
    return list(chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(ss, x), range(2, len(ss)+1))))

L = [tuple(sorted(y)) for x in df['country'].fillna('missing') 
                  for y in all_subsets(x.split(', '))]
print (L)

out = Counter(L)

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':out.keys(), 'col2': out.values()})
print (df)
                              col1  col2
0          (Poland, United States)     2
1                 (Norway, Poland)     1
2          (Norway, United States)     1
3  (Norway, Poland, United States)     1
```